# The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Salary, int

Tags: java, types, arguments, undefined, operator-keyword

```
public class Employee {

private int id = 0;
private String forename = null;
private String surname = null;
private Salary salary = null;
private CompanyPosition companyposition = null;

public Employee(){

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getForename() {
    return forename;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public Salary getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public String getPositionName() {
    return getPositionName();
}

public boolean eligibleForBonus(){

    boolean eligibleForBonus;

    if (salary > 40000) {

        eligibleForBonus = true;
    }

    else {
        eligibleForBonus = false;

    }

    return eligibleForBonus;
}
```

}

for the if statement it says the operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Salary, int. I'm new to Java and so I'm not too sure what do here. Salary is also a different class and salary is a variable within that class, it is of the double type.

Comment: You declare `salary` as an object of class `Salary` - how can you compare it with an int ?

Comment: You'll have to get the `salary` variable out of the `Salary` class and compare that.

Comment: Think this through logically: `>` is a mathematical operator that can only be used on numeric variables such as int, double, long, byte and such. Salary is class you've created that is *not* a numeric type (and can't become one) so the `>` makes no sense. Perhaps you want to compare the value of one of Salary's fields -- hard to know since we don't see Salary's code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare to the value of the variable in the `Salary` class. Assuming that double variable in the other class is called `salary`:

```
if (salary.salary > 40000) {
    ...
```

Or if the actual salary amount has a getter calle `getAmount` or something:

```
if (salary.getAmount()) {
    ...
```